# Calculating variance covariance matrix for improved kppm model

Tags: r, spatial, spatstat

I get the following error when I try to improve the intensity estimate of a kppm object, if I include the argument `vcov = TRUE` in the function `improve.kppm`:

```
Error in improve.kppm(object, type = type, rmax = rmax, dimyx = dimyx,  : 
  object 'gminus1' not found
```

If I don't include the argument, the function runs but I cannot use the `summary()` function on the improved kppm object. I get the same error message as above. The same thing happens when I use `vcov()`.

The call that I used to create my kppm object was (number of covariates has been reduced for clarity):

```
a05 = kppm(a2005nests ~ nest + nest2, cluster = "Thomas", covariates = fitcov(2))
```

where `fitcov(2)` is a function that returns a list of `im` objects. Could this be the issue? I've noticed that some spatstat functions on kppm objects throw errors if I used this function in the original `kppm` call. Usually it says something along the lines of `Error: Covariates ‘nest’ and ‘nest2’ were not found`.

Comment: Maybe as a first test could you run the command in two steps and see if that works: `covs = fitcov(2); a05 = kppm(a2005nests ~ nest + nest2, cluster = "Thomas", covariates = covs)`

Comment: Could you please post a reproducible example? I cannot recreate this using the built-in data set `bei` with covariates `elev` and `grad` in the list `bei.extra`. Can you reproduce the error with this data?

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. I couldn't reproduce the error with `bei`, just with my own data. I don't have time to investigate further at the moment, so I'll have to do without `improve.kppm` for now. But if I am able to reproduce it, I'll update this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in the logical flow of `improve.kppm`: if `vcov=TRUE` and `type != "quasi"`, the variable `gminus1` is not defined. We will fix this in the development version of `spatstat` as soon as possible.

Did you perhaps select `type="clik1"` or `type="wclik1"` in the original call to `kppm`?

For the moment, you should be able to avoid the bug by omitting the argument `type`, or explicitly selecting `type="quasi"`, in calls to `kppm` and `improve.kppm`.

The second problem, in which `kppm` fails to find the covariates, appears to be a scoping problem, but I can't reproduce it here. It would help if you can supply a minimal working example.

Comment: This is now fixed in spatstat development version 1.44-1.001 available from [the spatstat github site](https://github.com/spatstat/spatstat)